# Parsing xml file and getting parent names of nodes using stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

I have an xml file which is given as an input to a stored procedure in SQL Server. I have a table which has columns `element name` and `parent id`. The root element parent id is 0 the first element parent id is 1and so on. How do I achieve this?

I have several complex types in my xml

```
<VoyageOrderMessage xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="voyage.xsd">
    <MessageHeader>
            <MessageId>ID</MessageId>
            <MessageDate>2009-11-01T11:42:07.414+03:00</MessageDate>
            <MessageTypeVersion>Version</MessageTypeVersion>
            <SenderId>SI</SenderId>
            <ReceiverDetails>
                <ReceiverMethod />
                <ReceiverFormat />
                <ReceiverAddress></ReceiverAddress>
                </ReceiverDetails>
    </MessageHeader>
    <VoyageOrder>
            <VoyageID>RG-FUW-001</VoyageID>
            <Amendment>4</Amendment>
            <IMO>9256200</IMO>
            <VesselName>Fuwairit</VesselName>
            <ShipMasterName />
            <OrderDate>2009-11-01T11:41:59.149+03:00</OrderDate>
            <Passage>
                <PassageNumber>1</PassageNumber>
                <PassageType>Laden</PassageType>
                <DeparturePortName>Ras Laffan</DeparturePortName>
                <DeparturePortCode>RLF</DeparturePortCode>
                <DepartureTime>2009-10-06T19:06:00.000+03:00</DepartureTime>
                <ArrivalPortName>Suez</ArrivalPortName>
                <ArrivalPortCode>SUZ</ArrivalPortCode>
                <ArrivalTime>2009-10-13T03:00:00.000+02:00</ArrivalTime>
            </Passage>
```

Example output

```
elementname parent id column
------------------------------
voyageorder   0             1
messageheader 1           2
messageid     2           3
etc
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to store this in an XML column? Why take a perfectly good hierachical structure and turn it into a lousy heirachical implementation in a relational table? What I mean is; what is your ultimate problem because what you suggest is almost certaily the long way around.

Comment: how do i store it in xml column

Comment: OK, open Google search "SQL Server XML data type". Read the documents that you find. If you understand XML and SQL it should not take you long to get your head around it - watch for the need to `CROSS JOIN` when you query the XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the Edge Table Format returned by [OPENXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175160.aspx) is something you could use.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/2458)

**MS SQL Server 2012 Schema Setup**:

**Query 1**:

```
declare @xml xml = '
<VoyageOrderMessage xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="voyage.xsd">
    <MessageHeader>
            <MessageId>ID</MessageId>
            <MessageDate>2009-11-01T11:42:07.414+03:00</MessageDate>
    </MessageHeader>
    <VoyageOrder>
            <VoyageID>RG-FUW-001</VoyageID>
            <Amendment>4</Amendment>
            <OrderDate>2009-11-01T11:41:59.149+03:00</OrderDate>
            <Passage>
                <PassageNumber>1</PassageNumber>
                <PassageType>Laden</PassageType>
            </Passage>
    </VoyageOrder>
</VoyageOrderMessage>'

declare @idoc int

exec sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc output, @xml

select *
from openxml(@idoc, '*')

exec sp_xml_removedocument @idoc
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/2458/0)**:

```
| ID | PARENTID | NODETYPE |                 LOCALNAME | PREFIX |                              NAMESPACEURI | DATATYPE |   PREV |                                      TEXT |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  0 |   (null) |        1 |        VoyageOrderMessage | (null) |                                    (null) |   (null) | (null) |                                    (null) |
|  2 |        0 |        2 |                       xsi |  xmlns |                                    (null) |   (null) | (null) |                                    (null) |
| 14 |        2 |        3 |                     #text | (null) |                                    (null) |   (null) | (null) | http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance |
|  3 |        0 |        2 | noNamespaceSchemaLocation |    xsi | http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance |   (null) | (null) |                                    (null) |
| 15 |        3 |        3 |                     #text | (null) |                                    (null) |   (null) | (null) |                                voyage.xsd |
|  4 |        0 |        1 |             MessageHeader | (null) |                                    (null) |   (null) | (null) |                                    (null) |
|  5 |        4 |        1 |                 MessageId | (null) |                                    (null) |   (null) | (null) |                                    (null) |
| 16 |        5 |        3 |                     #text | (null) |                                    (null) |   (null) | (null) |                                        ID |
|  6 |        4 |        1 |               MessageDate | (null) |                                    (null) |   (null) |      5 |                                    (null) |
| 17 |        6 |        3 |                     #text | (null) |                                    (null) |   (null) | (null) |             2009-11-01T11:42:07.414+03:00 |
|  7 |        0 |        1 |               VoyageOrder | (null) |                                    (null) |   (null) |      4 |                                    (null) |
|  8 |        7 |        1 |                  VoyageID | (null) |                                    (null) |   (null) | (null) |                                    (null) |
| 18 |        8 |        3 |                     #text | (null) |                                    (null) |   (null) | (null) |                                RG-FUW-001 |
|  9 |        7 |        1 |                 Amendment | (null) |                                    (null) |   (null) |      8 |                                    (null) |
| 19 |        9 |        3 |                     #text | (null) |                                    (null) |   (null) | (null) |                                         4 |
| 10 |        7 |        1 |                 OrderDate | (null) |                                    (null) |   (null) |      9 |                                    (null) |
| 20 |       10 |        3 |                     #text | (null) |                                    (null) |   (null) | (null) |             2009-11-01T11:41:59.149+03:00 |
| 11 |        7 |        1 |                   Passage | (null) |                                    (null) |   (null) |     10 |                                    (null) |
| 12 |       11 |        1 |             PassageNumber | (null) |                                    (null) |   (null) | (null) |                                    (null) |
| 21 |       12 |        3 |                     #text | (null) |                                    (null) |   (null) | (null) |                                         1 |
| 13 |       11 |        1 |               PassageType | (null) |                                    (null) |   (null) |     12 |                                    (null) |
| 22 |       13 |        3 |                     #text | (null) |                                    (null) |   (null) | (null) |                                     Laden |
```

Answer (score 0):

In answer to the question authors first comment

```
CREATE TABLE Blah
(SomeData XML)

INSERT Blah
SELECT MyXMLinfo
```

Comment: please guys no one is forced to help